# How to create a pdf when add a post from admin panel in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pdf-generation

I want to create/generate a customized pdf file while adding a post from back end in WordPress.

Can some one guide/advise me how to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [Wordpress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How can I move this post to WordPress stack exchange site?

Comment: Sometimes moderator will do it for you (I don't recommend forcing them to do this), or you can just delete the question and remake it on the appropriate stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen anything on doing this from the admin panel but I have seen several plugins that allow you to create a PDF from the published content. The PDF & Print plugin is rated to work with the latest version of Wordpress 4.0 and has a fairly good feedback score.

Url for the plugin is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-print/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes true I haven't seen too but the technique/approach for generating pdf is really helpful for me. I know how to fetch all posted parameters in admin panel while adding a post. The only thing which I want to know how can generate the pdf in my customized format. For instance, If I have 3 different images in my post & some content, how can I put them all in one pdf file of my own designed template